# client specific file management through website

Tags: file-management, ftp

I have a bunch of client data that I publish monthly and the clients need to be able to access it. I want a solution where the client has their own credentials, goes to a site and logs in, then has access to their files to download. Essentially a glorified ftp site. I was wondering if there was any open source packages I could throw into IIS or a prepackaged solution that comes as a virtual appliance to host locally. I would prefer not to host this in the cloud.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some long searching, I ended up finding this http://www.projectsend.org/
which is exactly what I was looking for.